# What is the difference between email sends and individual email sents in Salesforce Marketing cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am new to Salesforce Marketing cloud.
I have configured marketing cloud connector and data is synced between SF and SFMC.

In Salesforce there are 2 sections namely Email sends and individual email sends in related list for contact.

What is the difference between Email sends and individual email sends in terms of use?

Also, if i send any mails via email sends records are getting added into Individual email sends. In which i can see some records for email sends.

Please help.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **Email Sends** list will only populate with email sends made to individual contacts / leads. If it's added onto the page layout, you will see that **Send Marketing Cloud Email** link in addition to the Unsubscribe and View Analytics link -- that is the link which allows you to send to a single person.

All sends to Reports / Campaigns / Salesforce Data Extensions will populate in the **Individual Email Results** related list, which can also be added to any Lead / Contact page layout.

Answer (score -1):

Also Individual Email Results will populate now if you send an email through a Journey, also to make sure you check the "Send Tracking Data to Sales Cloud" feature in email activity. This will also send the tracking data to Individual Email Results